# How to get an aborted child job to propagate it's aborted status instead of FAILED

Tags: jenkins

I have a pipeline stage that spawns child jobs in parallel. The parallel jobs are have failFast set to true.

If I manually abort one of the child jobs, all of the sibling jobs will get aborted due to the calling pipeline being cancelled. They will log "Calling Pipeline was cancelled" and "Finished: ABORTED".

However, the parent job that spawned all of the children will have it's status set to FAILURE.
"ERROR: Build Step #22350 completed with status ABORTED (propagate: false to ignore)
Finished: FAILURE"

How can I get the parent job to set its status to ABORTED instead of FAILURE?

Comment: Are you using declarative or scripted pipeline?

Comment: I wrote a Jenkinsfile for the pipeline, so I assume that would be scripted.

Comment: There are 2 types of pipelines: scripted or declarative.

Comment: Looking at examples of declarative, that does not appear to be what I am using. Also, I was unaware that there were multiple types. So, I believe I am using scripted.
How does that affect my question?

Comment: I was actually thinking about how you would catch the error and handle it to set the status yourself, which would differ between scripted and declarative. But after thinking about it further, that isn't right. This should just work as you expect it to. So I tried it on a 2.83 version with all upgraded plugins. This actually does reflect the correct Aborted status when a parallel task is aborted. It worked with failfast and without. So maybe you just need an upgrade.

Comment: I am currently running, 2.73.2. I will update and see if that resolves the issue. Thanks.

Comment: @KenLamb Did you find the answer to this? Having the same issue - latest version of everything.

Comment: I have not. At this point, I have worked around the issue and don't expect to investigate any further. Sorry.